# How to pass parameters to Spark SQL batch analytics in WSO2 DAS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

Im my scenario, I´d like to run a number of batch analytics queries changing just a few parameters. For instance, I´d like do change the range of dates to be used in the query.

WSO2´s point to spark sql docs, where UDFs are mentioned as a way to extend spark´s capabilities. Is this approach supported/recommended ?

TIA.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible in DAS. One solution for your case is, store the summarized data on DAS and then perform lucene query to fetch the proper results through DAS REST API by passing appropriate parameters. See (https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Analytics+REST+API+Guide)